# Powershell for querying ActiveDirectory

Tags: powershell

(Sorry if my English is bad, I'm a French guy).

I'm trying to automate some tasks on my AD and i was looking for a powershell commands which could list the users who didn't connect the last three months.
I tried using the lastlogontimestamp attribute but i can't make it work.
Here is what my command actually look like :

```
$date = new-object System.DateTime -ArgumentList @(2015,8,1,0,0,0)
Get-ADUser -Filter { -not (LastLogonTimeStamp -le "$date") }
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: (Don't worry about your English, that's pretty good anyway). Please explain in as much details as possible what your attempt actually does and what you expect it to do.

Comment: I was trying to identify the accounts i could have forgotten to disable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `lastLogonTimestamp` attribute is stored as a 64-bit integer representing a FILETIME timestamp.

You can convert your `DateTime` object to this format with the [`ToFileTime()` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tofiletime(v=vs.110).aspx).

I would suggest using the [`Get-Date` cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849887.aspx) rather than `New-Object System.DateTime`

```
# Current time -3 months:
$Threshold = (Get-Date).AddMonths(-3).ToFileTime()

# Retrieve the users
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(&(lastlogontimestamp < $Threshold))"
```